# Android internet permission ignored

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an application that requires the internet permission but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

To the manifest (above the application tag) and when I install the app my phone says: "No permissions requested" and the permission dialog doesn't show up.

However when I replace INTERNET with CAMERA like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

It works fine and shows up under the permissions tab in settings.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` with `android.permission.INTERNET`

Comment: So you don't have internet connection? Or you want to see your permissions there? what's your question?

Answer (score 5):

If the device is running Android 6.0 **(API level 23)** and the app's `targetSdkVersion` is **23 or higher** if an app declares in its manifest that it needs a **normal permission**, **the system automatically grants the app that permission at install time**.
The system does not prompt the user to grant normal permissions, and users cannot revoke these permissions.

As you can check in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) the [INTERNET](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission is normal.
Instead the [CAMERA](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html#CAMERA) permission is [dangerous](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're running your app in Android SDK>=23.

Internet permission is under **Normal permission** so it not show any permission prompt but Camera permission is under **Dangerous Permission** so it show permission prompt.

If an app declares that it needs a normal permission, the system automatically grants the permission to the app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Android only puts the [**dangerous** permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) there. And since Camera is a dangerous permissions you see it in the list, and since Internet is not, you don't see it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Android differentiates between normal permissions (e.g. INTERNET) and dangerous permissions (e.g. CAMERA). The User is only asked in case of dangerous permissions. So the behavior you see is perfectly normal.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Only Selected permissions can be asked for user

check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) which permissions can be asked by Permission manager

Answer (score -1):

This usually does the trick for me:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: The storage permission shows up but none of the others do for some reason