# Can't change permissions on android 10 and can't run webview

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am trying to set permissions to access the internet on my app but the permission manager won't let me do it. Therefore, I can't run web-view. The code below runs fine on Nougat. What is going on?

Here's is part of my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.droid_controls">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
        <activity
```

Here is the code to for the web-view:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

    WebView browser = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

and the html:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When I go to the app manager and try to change the permissions and tap on "Allowed" does not do anything. The strange part is the if I look at all permissions of the app, I see that matches my manifest. See the screenshots:

[image: app manager]

The permissions match the manifest.

[image: all permissions]

[image: code not running]

Tapping on anything is goes no where, and web-view does not load the page. What is going on?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE are normal permissions. They are granted automatically on installation, when your device runs on Android 6.0 or higher and your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher.

See also the [permissions documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174603/7756799)

Comment: Thanks but still not working. The web-view does NOT load the web-site. The same exact code runs find on Nougat. Any cluse?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, this was the issue.

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

[Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)